# Which driver for Intel HD Graphics should I install?

Tags: graphics, intel

Recently, I have replaced my old motherboard Giga G41M + Pentium 5500 CPU with the new Giga B75M + Celeron G540 CPU.

The old motherboard has an on-board GPU, Intel GMA X4500.

The new motherboard has no on-board GPU, but the new CPU has an on-die GPU, Intel HD Graphics.

I'm running Debian testing, without reinstall after upgraded the hardware. Command `lspci -vk` shows the driver `i915` is in use for the video:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device d000
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 43
        Region 0: Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Region 2: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0300c  Data: 4171
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
                AFCap: TP+ FLR+
                AFCtrl: FLR-
                AFStatus: TP-
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Now the problems,

- Though `i915` works, but it seems a bit of too slow. For example, it can only play the video "Ducks take off 1080p" less than 1 fps.
- Is `2nd generation...` lspci reported the right generation? In [the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Sixth_generation) it shows my Intel HD Graphics is the **6th** generation.
- Is `i915` the right driver for my Intel HD Graphics? It seems the module name for HD Graphics is `intel` from some Ubuntu sites. If so, I can't find the `intel` driver for Debian. Should I use the ubuntu sources.list? Where to get the `intel` driver?
- Or, maybe I can simply let Xorg to rescan the hardware and re-pick the right driver for me?

Comment: Did you install the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel`? That's the X driver. And `i915` is the correct *kernel* driver.